# $Ric$ flat metric on $S^n$.

Tags: riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, compact-manifolds

Suppose $\mathbb{R}\times S^{n}$ admits a complete riemannian metric $g$ such that $Ric_g = 0$. Prove that this metric $g$ induces a metric $\tilde g$ on $S^{n}$ such that $Rig_{\tilde g} = 0$. So far, I was able to prove the following. The manifold $M := \mathbb{R}\times S^{n}$ has two ends. Therefore, any complete metric has a line. By the splitting theorem of Cheeger-Gromoll, $M$ is a riemannian product $M = \mathbb{R} \times N$ for some manifold $N$. One can prove that $N$ has to be a compact orientable manifold and homotopic to the sphere. The splitting of the metric induces a metric $\tilde g$ on $N$ satisfying $Rig_{\tilde g} = 0$. If I'm not mistaken, $N$ is diffeomorphic to $S^n$ is a consequence of the Poincaré conjecture, but there must be a elementary way to prove this. Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: Poincaré conjecture only refers to dimension $3$, and moreover, there are exotic spheres in higher dimensions (for instance, in dimension $7$)

Comment: $N$ is a homotopy sphere and hence homeomorphic to $S^n$, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy_sphere). As $S^n$ has a unique smooth structure for $n \leq 3$, we see that $N$ is diffeomorphic to $S^n$. Since $\mathbb{R}\times S^n$ and $\mathbb{R}\times N$ are diffeomorphic, it follows that $S^n$ and $N$ are h-cobordant, see the proposition in [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/440371/21564). Therefore, $N$ is diffeomorphic to $S^n$ for $n \geq 5$ by the h-cobordism theorem. I'm not sure about $n = 4$ though (note, it is not known if exotic $S^4$'s exist).

Comment: @Didier thanks for your comment, intersting point that I was missing.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese thanks for your comment! Very intersting ideas. I wonder if there is a simpler argument. The statement is a passage from professor P. Petersen's Riemannian Geometry book, it reads as follows: "(...) we will see that if $\mathbb{R} \times S^n$ has $Ric \equiv 0$ then $S^n$ also has a metric with $Ric \equiv 0$", page 123 in my edition. To the best of my knowledge, this book does not develop the h-cobordism theorem, which I happen to not be familiar with. Thank you very much.

Comment: Somewhat related to this problem is the following. If you write a smooth manifold $M$ as a product of irreducible smooth manifolds, in the sense that they are not product of other manifolds, $M = M_1 \times \dots \times M_k$, then is this factorization unique up to order? Uniqueness is meant up to diffeomorphism of the factors. I did some research, and this statement is true for riemannian products, but I couldnt find much more.  I wonder if I should post it as another question.

Comment: @M.Rubick Is there any reference to the De Rham decomposition theorem (for Einstein metric for instance?)

Comment: No, such uniqueness fails already for products of surfaces and intervals.

Comment: @Didier the book presents a theorem, referred to as De Rham decomposition theorem, about the splitting of a manifold in terms of its holonomy groups. Do you think its related to this question? Thanks!

Comment: @MoisheKohan thanks for your comment, very intersting result. Could you elaborate on the counter-example? Thank you!

Comment: Take product of trice-punctured sphere and open interval. Do the same with once-punctured torus. The results are diffeomorphic.